# Javascript- Getting an uncaught type error

Tags: javascript

Creating a tic tac toe game, but for some reason, I'm getting an uncaught type error when doing observer.observe.

Here is the line where the error is occurring:

```
board.positions.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el,config));
```

Here is the function it is occurring in:

```
function TicTacToeGame() {
    const board = new Board();
    const humanPlayer = new HumanPlayer(board);
    const computerPlayer = new ComputerPlayer(board);
    let turn = 0;

    this.start = function () {
    const config = {childlist: true};
    const observer = new MutationObserver(()=> takeTurn());
    board.positions.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el,config));
   takeTurn();
    }
```

What is this error trying to say and what is the best way to resolve it.

Edit:
Here is the error I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': The options object must set at least one of 'attributes', 'characterData', or 'childList' to true.
```

Comment: **Exactly** what is the error? The complete error message?

Comment: What is `config` set to?

Comment: I don’t actually know. Where would I check that in the webstorm IDE

Comment: Here's [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit) for the options object that needs to be passed to `observe`. It explains the properties that need to be set (i.e. the ones mentioned in your error message).

Comment: The `config` must be `childList`, not `childlist` - (capital L).

Comment: Oh sorry, I see where you're setting `config`. Didn't notice it when first looking at your code.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I can't believe I didn’t notice that ‍♂️.